# vscode doesn't index project files

Tags: visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

Linux system (mint19, ubuntu kernel), C/C++ extension package has been installed, IntelliSense seems to be working, but cannot go to the definition at will, can only go after opening the file corresponding to the function, which seems vs code is not indexing all the source files when opening the project, so I had to manually open a file before I could have the memory ability of the functions. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and solved it?

tried re-install the C/C++ IntelliSense, re-enable, restart, still doesn't work, also tried clangd still doens't index the project files.

Comment: give us a [mre] with exact minimal code files and steps to reproduce the problem. show us a minimal intellisense configuration that is necessary to reproduce. copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: check also if any existing issue tickets match your problem. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Feature%3A+Go+to+Definition%22+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc